# When can you get a Google cached view of a deleted post?

Tags: discussion, google

I have observed that for most deleted questions on SE sites, you can not get a Google Cache version. I have some reasons to believe that for some deleted questions, you can in fact a Google Cache version. I speculate that the difference is in the way the question was deleted (possibly former are deleted by moderators and the latter are deleted automatically).

Can somebody clarify how exactly this works?

Comment: It's completely dependent on whether Google *has* a cache of it. It's nothing to do with us. A deleted question returns a 404 same as any other deleted question.

Comment: Its probably luck of the draw and whether the post was spidered already. Nothing we or SE does ought to be able to influence it directly

Comment: Probably boils down to how long and how many inbound links there were to the Q before it was deleted. For famous questions that were around a while but were latest deleted for not meeting the current charter of the site (eg “best boat for programmers”), odds are good. For Qs posted more recently and deleted quickly, probably bad. For trash Qs, likely zero.